# React: applying function parameters to closure breaks modularity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, react-redux

I've found the following pattern to be useful and common when generating nested JSX, but it also seems overly coupled:

```
const row = (x, y) => {


  return ({
     someKey: (z) => innerFunction(x,y,z)
  })

}
```

Here, `innerFunction` returns some JSX and requires `x,y,z` to be in scope

1. Is there a better way of writing/saying this? Or is this fine?
2. Is this a common pattern for others as well? Is it an anti-pattern?

Comment: It's valid. Whether there's a better way depends on your case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion-based. That being said, my *opinion* is that it's fine. If you think you may need to use `innerFunction` somewhere else, or sub something else for it in this context, make it a parameter to the outer function.

Comment: That's a really good idea! I'll do that. Thanks.